# Python langdetect: choose between one language or the other only

Tags: python, nlp, language-detection

I'm using `langdetect` to determine the language of a set of strings which I know are either in English or French.

Sometimes, `langdetect` tells me the language is Romanian for a string I know is in French.

How can I make `langdetect` choose between English or French only, and not all other languages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**Option 1**

One option would be using the package `langid` instead. Then you can simply restrict the languages with a method call:

```
import langid
langid.set_languages(['fr', 'en'])  # ISO 639-1 codes
lang, score = langid.classify('This is a french or english text')
print(lang) # en
```

**Option 2**

If you really want to use the `langdetect` package, you can copy the package folder (if you're not sure where it is, use `python -m site --user-site)` and remove the profiles you don't need from the folder `langdetect\profiles`.

This is not a very dynamic solution though.

Answer (score 5):

The way I'd do this is to use `detect_langs`, which returns a list of `Language` objects with probabilities, and then iterate through this list, returning the language if one of the options is English or French, or `None` if this isn't the case. This function works well for this purpose:

```
from langdetect import detect_langs

def englishOrFrench(string):
    res = detect_langs(string)
    for item in res:
        if item.lang == "fr" or item.lang == "en":
            return item.lang
    return None

print(englishOrFrench("Bonjour"))              # fr
print(englishOrFrench("The quick brown fox"))  # en
print(englishOrFrench("Hallo, mein Freund"))   # None
```

Comment: lang detect kinda.. sucks.  "38 HewcnonHe,!Me PlrIM HellaA.ne*aulee kicnon}le,wle npeAy(MOTpeHHbIX AorOBOpOM" is detected as en

Comment: @thang And what output would you expect from a perfect tool? langdetect tries to fit every string to some language so if you use it to detect meaningless strings it breaks of course.

Comment: I think that was copied from a russian pdf doc.

Comment: @thang Your example has almost nothing to do with Russian, it's a bogus copy output.

Comment: I agree detect_lang is not reliable. For half / half german-english text the predictions range from <0.1 to 0.5 for existence of german text over each run