# Getting wrong answer byy langdetect.detect

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I am using both Nltk and Scikit Learn to do some text processing. I have a data set containing of sentences that some of them has explained the situation in French and English(French part is duplicated)  which I want to delete french part. Following in one of my sentence:

"quipage de    Global Express     en provenance deTokyo  Japon  vers Dorval      a d   effectuer une remise des gaz sur la piste           cause d un probl  me de volets   Il fut autoris      se poser sur la piste     Les services d urgence n ont pas   t   demand  s     appareil s est pos   sans encombre   D  lai d environ   minutes sur l exploitation     The crew of    Global Express     from Tokyo  Japan  to Dorval      had to pull up on Rwy   at   because of a flap problem  It was cleared to land on Rwy    Emergency services were not requested  The aircraft touched down without incident  Delay of about   minutes to operations         Regional Report of  m d y        with   record s "

I want to remove all words that are in French. I have tried following code so far but the result is not good enough.

```
x=sentence
x=x.split()
import langdetect      
from langdetect import detect 
for word in x:
lang=langdetect.detect(word)
if lang=='fr':
    print(word)
    x.remove(word)
```

the following is my output:

```
l
un
sur
une
oiseaux
avoir
un
le
du
un
est
```

Is this a good approach? how I can improve its performance in order to reach better results.

Answer (score 1):

Language detection usually requires at least a longer sentence to do a decent job. One or two short words is probably not going to be enough. Think about `a` in `Dorval a d effectuer` above. Is `a` by itself French or English? Is `Tokyo` French?

I'd also double-check whether this library can handle the kind of non-standard French (no accents, no apostrophes, missing letters, etc.) that you have in your data by checking to see what the library detects for longer strings. It's possible the library is only good at figuring out that more standard French is French. For example, `d'un problème` vs. your data: `d un probl me`.

See also this question for other approaches where you can restrict the possible set of languages: [Python langdetect: choose between one language or the other only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235932/python-langdetect-choose-between-one-language-or-the-other-only)

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact French words had accents and apostrophes, I removed it since with them the following error had been appeared. '''No features in text''. I came across the following code but it did not work.                                    def unusual_words(text):
  text_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in text if w.isalpha())
  english_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())
  unusual = text_vocab.difference(english_vocab)
  return sorted(unusual)

Comment: If your goal is language detection, it's probably better not to do that kind of preprocessing. The accents are very good clues about French vs. English.

Comment: You are right. I would definitely check that. Thanks